# Delay in php redis update with sleep or long task

Tags: php, redis, delay, sleep

I'm trying simulate a large php method where I increase a redis value at first, and I decrease that redis value at end, to know in "real time" how many people I have in that process.

To simulate this I have tried with sleep, usleep and large "for", but the redis increment with this method, has a little delay (15-25 seconds) by request, so I don't know if this is a real behaviour or if this is a problem with for/sleep/usleep.

The code is:

```
function start() {

   $redis->incr('people_active');

   sleep(60);

   $redis->decr('people_active');

}
```